# Create Rubber Band with rotation using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

To start I am going to be upfront, I am trying to add a feature to a QGIS Plugin Called instantprint. I am trying to add rotation to the tool so that you can align features to the print box and have them print in that orientation.
First I managed to successfully create a python function to capture the rotation value of the canvas and apply it to the map in the composer *see below*

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def CanvasRotation(feature, parent):
    return (iface.mapCanvas().rotation())
```

This function can be used in the data defined rotation like `CanvasRotation()` so that your map rotation matches your canvas. This allows you to use your map rotation to set how you want the map to be aligned.

The issue I am into now is the Map box is defined by the extent of the Map view port which skewes due to the rotation. So I changed the rubber band def to incorporate the roation in hopes to resolve this.

Original Code:

```
 def __createRubberBand(self):
    self.__cleanup()
    extent = self.mapitem.extent()
    center = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
    self.corner = QPointF(center.x() - 0.5 * extent.width(), center.y() - 0.5 * extent.height())
    self.rect = QRectF(self.corner.x(), self.corner.y(), extent.width(), extent.height())
    self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))
    self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
    self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
    self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 127))

    self.pressPos = None
```

I added the rotation math to the `self.corner =` part to:

```
def __createRubberBand(self):
    self.__cleanup()
    extent = self.mapitem.extent()
    center = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
    self.corner = (QPointF(center.x - ((((((0.5)*(extent.width)))*((math.cos(iface.mapCanvas().rotation()))))-((((0.5)*(extent.width)))*((math.sin(iface.mapCanvas().rotation()))))))), (center.y - ((((0.5)*(extent.width)))*((math.sin(iface.mapCanvas().rotation()))))+((((0.5)*(extent.width)))*((math.cos(iface.mapCanvas().rotation()))))))
    self.rect = QRectF(self.corner.x(), self.corner.y(), extent.width(), extent.height())
    self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))
    self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
    self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
    self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 127))
```

The plugin loads up but when I run it I get an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`.

I added all the imports I needed for the functions I am using, not sure what I did wrong. I checked my math a few times and didn't see any issues there but I might have missed something there are quite a few bracks. It almost looks like the results of the math are not what the tool is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is related with `(0.5)*(extent.width)`. You try to multiply a float (`0.5`) by a method (`extent.width`). `width` doesn't call the method. To call a method, you have to use parentheses. So it has to be `extent.width()`. Also `center.x` and `center.y` have to be `center.x()` and `center.y()`. You used all in original code correctly, but missed in the next one.

Try in this way:

```
def __createRubberBand(self):
    self.__cleanup()
    extent = self.mapitem.extent()
    center = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()

    r = iface.mapCanvas().rotation()    
    rs = math.sin(r)
    rc = math.cos(r)    
    w = 0.5 * extent.width() ##
                                  ##                              ##
    self.corner = QPointF(center.x() - (w * rc - w * rs), center.y() - (w * rs + w * rc))
    self.rect = QRectF(self.corner.x(), self.corner.y(), extent.width(), extent.height())
    self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))
    self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
    self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
    self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 127))
```

I'm not sure if it solves your other problem, but it helps you not to get that error.

Comment: I clearly see what is going on and the error goes away when I implement that code but it doesn't seem to change how the tool responds when compared to the original. I am left to thinking I must be changing the wrong spot to get my desired result. Thank you for the help